# Повторная отправка/получение данных с сервера через ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, form

Вот пример кода:

```
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; Charset=UTF-8">  
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
</head>  

<body>  

    <form id="myForm">  
    Введите имя:<br/>  
        <input id="username" type="text" size="20"><br/><br/>  
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить">  
    </form>  

    <div id="content"></div>  

    <script>  
        $(document).ready(function(){  

            $('#myForm').submit(function(){  
                $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "greetings.php",  
                    data: "username="+$("#username").val(),  
                    success: function(html){  
                        $("#content").html(html);  
                    }  
                });  
                return false;  
            });  

        });  
    </script>  

</body>  
</html>
```

Здесь при нажатии на кнопку «Отправить» в форме данные отправляются скрипту greetings.php, где обрабатываются и результат выводится в блок с id="content".
И это работает.

Но при повторной отправке формы (без предварительной перезагрузки страницы) — это не срабатывает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `Но при повторной отправке формы (без предварительной перезагрузки страницы) — это не срабатывает.` - как ты пытался сделать повторную отправку?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте такую структуру:
Где `e.preventDefault();` сбрасывает действие по умолчанию. То есть форма не будет отправляться через HTML. А строка `var formData = new FormData( $(this).get(0) );` сформирует данные для отправки.

```js
 $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData( $(this).get(0) );

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(responce){

        },
        error: function(responce){

        }

    });
});
```

```html
     <form method="POST" action="greetings.php" id="myForm">  
        Введите имя:<br/>  
            <input id="username" type="text" size="20"><br/><br/>  
            <input type="submit" value="Отправить">  
     </form>
```